# UPDATE two columns based on JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This should be a simple `UPDATE`, which in my opinion should update the same record twice on two different columns, but it doesn't work.

A simplified sample code:

```
DECLARE @nowWithDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @result TABLE(Id INT, Poll1Date DATETIME, Poll2Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @result VALUES(1, NULL, NULL)

;WITH data(Id, IsPoll1, IsPoll2) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 1, 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 1
)
UPDATE r
SET Poll1Date = IIF(d.IsPoll1 = 1, @nowWithDate, Poll1Date),
    Poll2Date = IIF(d.IsPoll2 = 1, @nowWithDate, Poll2Date)
FROM @result r
JOIN data d ON d.Id = r.Id

SELECT * FROM @result
```

I can't figure it out, why the second date not updated? It looks like this row is updated only once.

Comment: `why the second date is not provided?` ... what does this mean?

Comment: Think about it. You've got two rows in `data` that match the ID `@result`, and you're updating both columns in `@result` each time. Whichever row it processes second overwrites the values updated from the first update, no? Sounds like you need to group on the ID in your update statement and use MAX on the `IsPoll` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @nowWithDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @result TABLE(Id INT, Poll1Date DATETIME, Poll2Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @result VALUES(1, NULL, NULL)

;WITH data(Id, IsPoll1, IsPoll2) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 1, 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 0, 1
)
select * from data
```

This returns 2 rows. So, when you join it with `@results` it updates from the first row only. For the first row, IsPoll1=1 but IsPoll2=0, So, second one is not updated.

To update both the rows,

```
DECLARE @nowWithDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @result TABLE(Id INT, Poll1Date DATETIME, Poll2Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @result VALUES(1, NULL, NULL)

;WITH data(Id, IsPoll1, IsPoll2) AS
(
select Id, SUM (IsPoll1),SUM(IsPoll2) from(
    SELECT 1 as Id, 1 as IsPoll1, 0 as IsPoll2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as Id,0 as IsPoll1,  1 as IsPoll2) d1
    group by d1.Id
)
UPDATE r
SET Poll1Date = IIF(d.IsPoll1 = 1, @nowWithDate, Poll1Date),
    Poll2Date = IIF(d.IsPoll2 = 1, @nowWithDate, Poll2Date)
FROM @result r
JOIN data d ON d.Id = r.Id

SELECT * FROM @result
```